# How to get the comma after every 2nd digit from the right in excel..?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to insert comma after every 2nd digit from right in Excel

for eg:

123 ---> 1,23.00

1234 ---> 12,34.00

12345  ---> 1,23,45.00

12345678  ---> 12,34,56,78.00

Answer (score 5):

`=TEXT(A1,IFERROR(REPT("##\,",ROUNDUP(LEN(A1)/2-1,0)),"")&"#0.00")`

Out of curiosity, what will you be using it for?